# How do I calculate mean on filtered rows of a pandas dataframe and append means to all columns of original dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

How can I calculate all column's mean to ONLY rows that aren't equal to zero and append a new row at the bottom with the averages with only one line of code?  It doesn't have to be one line, but I'm wondering why this doesn't work?

The code below ignores the (df.bar != 0) piece

```
df = df.append(df[(df.bar != 0)].mean(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
```

Example df:

```
    foo     bar     total
0   foo1    bar1    293.09
1   foo2    0       0
2   foo3    bar3    342.3
```

Current Result:

```
0   foo     bar     total
1   foo1    bar1    293.09
2   foo2    0       0
3   foo3    bar3    342.3
4                   211.796
```

Desired Result:

```
0   foo     bar     total
1   foo1    bar1    293.09
2   foo2    0       0
3   foo3    bar3    342.3
4                   317.695
```

Comment: Need `!=` instead `<>` because python.

Comment: Should be `df.bar != '0'` with quotes, since it's a string. i.e `df.append(df[(df.bar != '0')].mean(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As John Galt commented need `'0'` because `0` is string:

```
df = df.append(df[(df.bar != '0')].mean(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    foo   bar    total
0  foo1  bar1  293.090
1  foo2     0    0.000
2  foo3  bar3  342.300
3   NaN   NaN  317.695
```

If need remove `NaN`s in last row only use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with parameter `fill_value`:

```
s = df[(df.bar != '0')].mean(numeric_only=True).reindex(df.columns, fill_value='')
df = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    foo   bar    total
0  foo1  bar1  293.090
1  foo2     0    0.000
2  foo3  bar3  342.300
3              317.695
```

Another solution - [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = s
print (df)
    foo   bar    total
0  foo1  bar1  293.090
1  foo2     0    0.000
2  foo3  bar3  342.300
3              317.695
```

Comment: Optional `.fillna('')` at the end for Op's output